# Firefox javascript redirect in ajax callback results white screen

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, redirect, window.location

I am trying to redirect Firefox from current address **url_1** to **url_2** in ajax callback function doing this:

```
window.location = url_2
```

After this line of code executes, the address line shows the same **url_1**, but the window of browser shows nothing but white screen and hangs in this state.

I've tried different ways with the same negative result:

```
window.location.assign(url_2)

window.location.replace(url_2)

window.location = url_2
return false;

window.location.href = url_2
```

Also I've noticed that insertion of alert('something') before window.location results Firefox to work fine and after the dialogue window closure the redirection to **url_2** occurs.

Other browsers make the redirection without any problem.

How to solve this issue?

The rest of the code:

```
initializeViewModels = function (data, submitUrl) {

    // Handler of "submit" button click
    $(".submit").click(function () {
        var json = ko.toJSON(window.viewModel);

        //Submiting data to the server
        $.ajax({
            url: submitUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: json,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: callback
        });
    });

    var callback = function (data) {
        var url_2 = window.myViewUrl + '/' + data.Id.toString();
        window.location = url_2;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1):

The hang is caused by the callback function. Since the AJAX call is not fully closed, the garbage collector creates a problem when trying to unload the page before reaching the requested url_2.

Instead of having your `window.location.replace()` line in the AJAX `onSuccess` callback directly, you can use `setTimeout(window.location.replace(),5);` this should fix the problem as this will execute the task asynchronously, outside of the AJAX closure.

Comment: Thank you for a good idea about the callback function.
I've just tried setTimeout in all the above ways  - the result is still the same white screen. :-(

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I was sure it was the problem. Could you then post more code?